# How to set tld_length dynamically on a Rails app with puma (thread safe)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, rack, puma

We have a Rails app that responds to multiple TLDs, including subdomains. One of those domains is a `.co.uk.`  domain, therefore the TLD length in that case is 2 (eg: `ourapp.es`, `ourapp.co.uk`, `api.ourapp.es`, `api.ourapp.co.uk`.

In order to dynamically change the TLD length we've using [this Rack middleware](https://github.com/WeAreFarmGeek/tld_length/blob/master/lib/rack/tld_length.rb):

```rb
class Rack::TldLength

  def initialize(app, host_pattern, host_tld_length)
    @app = app
    @host_pattern = Regexp.new(host_pattern)
    @host_tld_length = host_tld_length
  end

  def call(env)
    original_tld_length = tld_length

    request = Rack::Request.new(env)

    set_tld_length(@host_tld_length) if request.host =~ @host_pattern

    @app.call(env)
  ensure
    set_tld_length(original_tld_length)
  end

  private

  def tld_length
    ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length
  end
  def set_tld_length(length)
    ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = length
  end
end
```

This has been working so far until **we decided to migrate from Unicorn to puma**. With Unicorn each request would go to a different unicorn worker (process) and there was no problem. However with puma each request can be processed by a different thread. We suspect that changing the value `ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length` is not thread safe, but we're struggling to find an alternative to this.

It seems that the Rails routing (where we define routes with subdomain constraints) depends on setting the `ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length` properly.

Is there any workaround to keep the concurrency offered by having multiple threads while still being able to handle multiple domains with different TLD lengths?

Answer (score 1):

You state that:

> It seems that the Rails routing (where we define routes with subdomain constraints) depends on setting the ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length properly.

It seems to me that the easiest way is to normalize the `"HOST"` parameter in the `env` to allow for all host names to behave equally.

i.e.

```
# Place this middleware at the top of the chain, before any Rails middleware.
class Rack::FixedHost

  # a host_pattern can be: /(foo.com|foo.co.uk|foo.bor.co.uk)$/
  def initialize(app, host_pattern, normalized_host)
    @app = app
    @host_pattern = Regexp.new(host_pattern)
    @normalized_host = normalized_host
  end

  def call(env)
    env[:ORIGINAL_HOST] = env['HTTP_HOST'.freeze] || @normalized_host
    env[:ORIGINAL_DOMAIN] = env[:ORIGINAL_HOST].match(@host_pattern).to_a[0] || @normalized_host
    env['HTTP_HOST'.freeze] = env[:ORIGINAL_HOST].to_s.sub(@host_pattern, @normalized_host)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

To clarify: normalizing a host means that it always has the same host name postfix, regardless of the original postfix, allowing for easier subdomain extraction.

i.e., for `sub.foo.com`, `sub.foo.co.uk` and `sub.foo.bor.co.uk` the `normalized_host` will always be `sub.foo.com`.

In this example, `sub` is easily extracted after the different host variation (`foo.com`, `foo.co.uk` and `foo.bor.co.uk`) have all been normalized to the single "normalized" variation (`foo.com`).

By default, methods such as [`url_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) will construct a relative URL, so the actual host name isn't important.

However, if you use [`url_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) or other functions to provide a complete URL, you might consider using an explicit `:host` to direct traffic to the regional host name you're using. i.e.:

```
url_for(action: 'index', host: "admin.#{request.env[:ORIGINAL_DOMAIN]}")
```

This, of course could be made even more powerful by extracting the original domain name before normalizing the host, allowing you to route to specific subdomains while keeping the regional domain.

---

Note (my original observation / answer):

Your code stores the TLD length of each request in a shared global variable.

When two parallel requests arrive, on two different threads, it is a matter of chance to know which TLD length will be used (the last one written, most probably, if no data "shearing" occurs).

A thread-safe approach will store the information in the `env` variable, allowing each request it's own TLD length.

The following example will NOT work, because I don't handle TLD lengths and have no idea how to calculate them... but it shows the use of the `env` as a thread-safe per-request storage.

```
class Rack::TldLength

  def initialize(app, host_pattern, host_tld_length)
    @app = app
    @host_pattern = Regexp.new(host_pattern)
    @default_tld_length = host_tld_length
  end

  def call(env)
    # ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length = @default_tld_length if(env["HTTP_HOST".freeze].to_s =~ @host_pattern)
    env[:hosts_tld] = (env["HTTP_HOST".freeze].to_s =~ @host_pattern) ? @default_tld_length : ActionDispatch::Http::URL.tld_length
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm not sure what do you mean by normalizing the host parameter. In other words, what would be the input value for `normalized_host`?

Comment: I do not think that normalizing the HOST parameter will help at all, because the HOST includes the full domain. The `tld_length` parameter is used in splitting HOST into `domain` and `subdomain` components. Unfortunately, `@@tld_length` is used in other functions, so to be thread safe you would have to find and rewrite all those functions as well as provide thread-local storage.

Comment: @jävi - Normalizing a host means that it always has the same host name postfix, regardless of the original postfix. i.e., for `www.foo.com`, `www.foo.co.uk` and `www.foo.bor.co.uk` the `normalized_host` will always be `www.foo.com`

Comment: @jävi - I tried clarifying my answer with examples about HOST normalization. If you use the middleware I provided, place it before the Rails middleware, so Rails calculates information based on the normalized HOST value.

Comment: @OldPro I'm not sure why normalizing the `HOST` value won't work. Can you explain?

Comment: But with this approach, Rails routing helpers would use the normalized host to construct URLs, therefore links that should go to `foo.co.uk` will point to `foo.com` instead. Am I wrong?

Comment: @jävi - the URL construction **should** be relative (resulting in relative URLs rather than absolute URLs)... but, I've been coding straight up Rack for a while and I don't remember if there are cases in which Rails will generate a full-length URL (perhaps for WebSockets?). URL generation could be solved in another way, perhaps using custom URL generation methods or wrapping the original ones and replacing the normalized host name with the original host name.

Comment: @jävi - I updated my answer to save the original (non-normalized) URL. Also, please note that the default Rails behavior is to construct a relative URL (see [the `url_for` method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)).

Answer (score 0):

`ActionDispatch::Http::URL` stores `tld_length` as a [module variable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/813af4655f9bf3c712cf50205eebd337070cee52/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L11), which is to say as a single global variable for your whole application. There is no way to make that thread safe. I suspect the design thinking was that your app would be at just one domain and so one global setting, set at startup, would be sufficient, so it was not necessary to make `tld_length` thread safe.

ActionDispatch is pretty central to Rails, so I would try to avoid mucking with it. How hard would it be to run 2 Puma servers and send all `tld_length = 2` traffic to one server and `tld_length = 1` to the other server? If you are running a server farm, that would be a reasonable sharding key and would keep you from having to do any further tricks.

If I had to run it in 1 server, I would look into modifying `ActionDispatch::Http::URL` so that it stores `tld_length` in a Thread-local variable instead of a module variable and set it on each request. You would also have to change the functions that use the module variable as a default value, like [`domain`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/813af4655f9bf3c712cf50205eebd337070cee52/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L330) to use the thread variable as the default, which might be easiest by using an accessor function.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The reason to move from Unicorn to Puma was to take advantage of multiple threads (which require less memory) as opposed to multiple workers (which require a full copy of the app process for each worker). We do run multiple servers in the form of multiple containers and workers (processes), but we need to reduce our app's memory footprint (by using threads).

Comment: @jävi I understand the move to threads. What I am saying is you can run 1 Puma server that only handles `tld_length=1` and another Puma server that only handles `tld_length=2` and then use `nginx` or something in front of them so that requests from different domains are sent to the server with the matching configuration. That would avoid the issue of `tld_length` not being thread safe because it would safely be the same for all threads. Otherwise your only choice is to rewrite (parts of) ActionDispatch or not use it at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Having a different a Puma worker for handling only tld_length=2 is an original solution but wouldn't help with doing proper load balancing. 

I've ended up creating a PR to Rails to make tld_length thread-safe, which was easier than I expected:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39946

I really appreciate your response anyways! thank you!

Comment: @jävi Glad I could help. I did not know about `thread_mattr_accessor`, that is a good solution. May I have the bonus anyway, please?